# XML Output Not Recognized

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a utility which monitors license usage and writes to a file in XML format, but the problem is it also writes text format in the XML file, so when adding this file into access or Excel for further reporting, it does not recognize the output file as an XML file.

Here is the command that I run as part of the batch file and this batch file is run on an hourly basis, so the output is appended every time.

slmcmd -montts prod-sql -port 6005 >> C:\temp\license_usage.xml

The output is like this..

Retrieving monitoring data from license-server.
    License-server host : prod-sql
    License-server port : 6005
    Monitoring type     : Totals

Result:

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<totals
    date="Wed Jul 29 19:38:24 2015"
    host="prod-sql.eohcorp.net"
    port="6005"
    udpPort="6005"
    mode="master">
    <desktopLicense
        count="0"
    />
    <concurrentLicense
        count="9">
        <product
            id="7114"
        />
        <product
            id="7115"
        />
        <product
            id="7116"
        />
        <product
            id="7117"
        />
        <product
            id="7118"
        />
        <product
            id="10056"
            count="12"
        />
        <product
            id="10365"
        />
        <product
            id="10896"
            count="0"
        />
        <product
            id="10996"
            count="81"
        />
    </concurrentLicense>
    <userLicense
        count="0"
    />
    <serverLicense
        count="2">
        <product
            id="7056"
            count="16"
        />
        <product
            id="10146"
        />
    </serverLicense>
</totals>`
```

OK

So, the first 6 lines and the last line are not in the XML format, I can search and delete the lines but I am looking for an efficient way of removing these lines from the output.

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: First six lines are indeed proper XML format as they are attributes in the `totals` tag. Try removing the backticks at the very beginning and end. Finally, do note, MS Access' XML import feature does not handle attribute-centric xml files as this is, only element-centric. Excel requires proper mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the command should generate correct XML. If there is no way to fix it, and you need to use the batch file workaround, give this a try (assuming the root element is always "totals"):

```
slmcmd -montts prod-sql -port 6005 >> C:\temp\license_usage.txt
REM Pick everything except lines containing "`<" or ">`"
findstr /v /C:"`<" /v /C:">`" license_usage.txt > license_usage.xml
REM Append closing root element
echo ^</totals^>>> license_usage.xml
```